# spring-amqp: Channel shutdown with NACKS RECEIVED message

Tags: spring-amqp

Using spring-amqp with heavy load on RabbitMQ bus, we sometimes get logs from org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory saying :
**Channel shutdown: clean channel shutdown; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=200, reply-text=NACKS RECEIVED, class-id=0, method-id=0)**

Can you explain this log, please, and why is it at ERROR level?
Do we have any adjustments to make?
Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The channel throws an exception if all publisher confirms are not returned with the timeout...

```java
@Override
public void waitForConfirmsOrDie(long timeout)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException
{
    try {
        if (!waitForConfirms(timeout)) {
            close(AMQP.REPLY_SUCCESS, "NACKS RECEIVED", true, null, false);
            throw new IOException("nacks received");
        }
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        close(AMQP.PRECONDITION_FAILED, "TIMEOUT WAITING FOR ACK");
        throw(e);
    }
}
```

The `DefaultChannelCloseLogger` will only skip normal closes (200) if the reply text is `OK`...

```java
/**
 * Return true if the {@link ShutdownSignalException} reason is AMQP.Channel.Close and
 * the reply code was AMQP.REPLY_SUCCESS (200) and the text equals "OK".
 * @param sig the exception.
 * @return true for a normal channel close.
 */
public static boolean isNormalChannelClose(ShutdownSignalException sig) {
    Method shutdownReason = sig.getReason();
    return isNormalShutdown(sig) ||
            (shutdownReason instanceof AMQP.Channel.Close
                && AMQP.REPLY_SUCCESS == ((AMQP.Channel.Close) shutdownReason).getReplyCode()
                && "OK".equals(((AMQP.Channel.Close) shutdownReason).getReplyText()));
}
```

If you want to ignore these errors, you can configure a custom close exception logger:

```java
/**
 * Set the strategy for logging close exceptions; by default, if a channel is closed due to a failed
 * passive queue declaration, it is logged at debug level. Normal channel closes (200 OK) are not
 * logged. All others are logged at ERROR level (unless access is refused due to an exclusive consumer
 * condition, in which case, it is logged at INFO level).
 * @param closeExceptionLogger the {@link ConditionalExceptionLogger}.
 * @since 1.5
 */
public void setCloseExceptionLogger(ConditionalExceptionLogger closeExceptionLogger) {
    Assert.notNull(closeExceptionLogger, "'closeExceptionLogger' cannot be null");
    this.closeExceptionLogger = closeExceptionLogger;
    if (this.publisherConnectionFactory != null) {
        this.publisherConnectionFactory.setCloseExceptionLogger(closeExceptionLogger);
    }
}
```